# VS 2019 - ASP.NET - Publish File System - No Dialog Window After Re-Install

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-web-deploy

I am running Visual Studio 2019 and had no issues running publish to file system until an admin uninstalled Visual Studio a couple weeks ago by mistake and I had to re-install. Post re-install everything appeared to be working fine until I went to use the Publish wizard. As you can see from the below screen shots, when I right click on the project and select Publish the wizard never appears. At first I thought it was an issue with my profile so I created a new profile and logged into the machine with and launched VS2019 and tried to publish and the same thing happened. If I copy the website to another machine with Visual Studio no issues.

How can I get the publish wizard working again?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio or installing the latest VS 2022?

Comment: Have you installed all of the webforms workflows? The webforms bits and parts are not installed by default, so you need to install the additional legacy workflows.

Comment: Thank you @MinxinYu-MSFT, I will attempt a re-install and let you know how it goes

Comment: Thank you @AlbertD.Kallal, Yes I have installed all the webforms workflows and components.

Comment: does the project build and run before you attempt to publish? (so, does hitting f5 after opening the web site work? I mean, no use trying to publish a site if it don't run in the first place, right?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yes it does